# How do I override the "This image has been removed" message?

Tags: 8, media

I'm using Drupal 8.0.0-beta10. I just tried to add a new basic page node that contains an image hosted in an external website: While it's showing up in the preview, the image isn't showing up once the node is published; when I hover over the broken image, it shows the following message.

> This image has been removed. For security reasons, only images from the local domain are allowed.

How do I override this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you need to know which input text filter you have enabled where the images are not showing. For the sake of this answer, let's say it's the **"Basic HTML"** input filter.

Go to the configuration for this input filter, such as `/admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html`

Scroll down to "Enabled Filters" and look for:

**"Restrict images to this site"**
Disallows usage of  tag sources that are not hosted on this site by replacing them with a placeholder image.

[image]

If you can not view externally-hosted images, it is likely this filter is enabled. Simply disable this filter.

Comment: I came across this when using the CDN module. Screenack has the right answer, but if you're a more visual person, here's a 90s video showing the effect and to make the fix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBfB8QCtvIA